# Cannot save even a new document

Tags: saving

I was using Blender for some time without issue.
Recently I have found I am unable to save even a brand new document.

I am given the error message: "cannot open file  for writing: No such file or directory".

I have seen a similar post before which simply recommended blender needs to be run with administrator privileges. **The account that is unable to save is the administrator**.

I have posted a query to the microsoft forums but I also wished to see if there is a chance this is a blender issue.

Thanks

Comment: I don't use Windows so I'm not sure what the problem could be, but are you trying to save to a directory which has (or whose parent directories have) spaces or punctuation in their name?

Comment: No. Even just saving under C:\ will not work.
I have checked for windows errors using system file checker and DISM, so far nothing found.

I do also have sufficient space to save, in case anyone was wondering.

Comment: I have read that discussion. 
It was closed because it was 'off topic' and no answer was given besides "blender needs administrative rights", which I've already confirmed I do have.

Comment: I tried to create a new user profile on windows for testing purposes. 
I of course found I had to reinstall blender for the new user, so i did.

Now that I have done that, I found I could save a new document fine under the new user.

And yet when I reinstall for my main user I cannot, even if I try deleting any user preferences files.

Comment: With your last comment, it sounds like this issue is not caused by Blender, but another part of your system (settings). Hence, it is like to be closed because it is not in scope of blender.stackexchange.com. You could try to ask at superuser.se? If it is about a Blender-specific setting it can be reopened. You can always update your original question be editing it or reopen a new question if you have found out other sources of the problem. Welcome to Blender.se

Comment: I am corresponding with microsoft on their forums to determine if it is a windows issue.

I posted here to see if anyone can recommend any steps to actually check this, rather than just saying "sounds like a windows thing"